# django-xhtml2pdf - Generate pdf (codec can't decode byte)

Tags: django

```
def preview_pdf(request, did):
    d_instance = get_object_or_404(MyObject, pk=did, user=request.user)
    #resp = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    result = generate_pdf('pdf_preview.html')

    return render_to_response('pdf_preview.html', {'objects': d_instance,'result':result}, RequestContext(request))
```

pdf_preview.html:

```
{{result}}

<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url={{result}}.pdf&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>

{{objects.name}}
```

but does not display the document.

`{{result}}` is displayed like: `<StringIO.StringIO instance at 0xb4da030c>`

Comment: Do you need to pass a `HttpResponse` object to the `generate_pdf` function?

Comment: @PauloBu I need display me generated pdf in iframe. `{{ result }}` looks like `<StringIO.StringIO instance at 0xb1f99aec>`

Comment: And you are converting `pdf_preview.html` to pdf am I right? Can you post the content of `pdf_preview.html`?

Comment: @PauloBu Yes. I try convert `pdf_preview.html` to pdf. I updated question

Comment: It seems `{{result}}` is a buffer, buffer doesn't have defined the `__unicode__` method to convert to string, that's the reason why when you render it, it shows the name of the class. I'm not sure about how to do this, I'm not exactly clear what do you want to do. Try to do `{{result.read}}` anyways to see what happens :)

Comment: @PauloBu `{{result.read}}` display blank page. Mayby I should use https://github.com/chrisglass/django-xhtml2pdf/blob/master/django_xhtml2pdf/utils.py#L40 this function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need set codec parameter, for encode content in PDF
You need something like this:

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from datetime import datetime
import StringIO

def pdf_report(request, did):
    d_instance = get_object_or_404(MyObject, pk=did, user=request.user)

    contents = render_to_string('pdf_preview.html', {'object':d_instance})
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=answer_%s.pdf' % (f_date,)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(contents.encode('utf-8')), result, show_error_as_pdf=True, encoding='UTF-8')
    if not pdf.err:
        response.write(result.getvalue())
        result.close()
        return response
```

And you may load this created document in another frame.

Comment: How to load this? Via url for this view? `<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/myview/1/preview" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>`. This document is downloaded, not displayed

Comment: May be you need full file name for src with "pdf" extension?